# How can I merge two shapefiles with different attributes but are in the same geographic space

Tags: r, merge, gis, geospatial, geo

I'm trying to merge datasets of city council shapefiles with census blocks. I want to be able to see all of the census blocks that lie within each city council district.

I've tried bind and combine, but the resulting attribute table has NA values for most rows.

I want the resulting attribute table to look like:

```
    CC District 1          -x, -y         block 101
    CC District 1           -x+1,-y-1     block 102
    CC District 1          -x-1,-y+1      block 103
    CC District 2        -x-2, -y+1       block 104

etc
```

Here is my code:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(tidyr)
library(foreign)

nycc21 <- sf::read_sf('nycc.shp') %>%
  sf::st_transform('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
nycb20 <- sf::read_sf('nycb2020.shp') %>%
  sf::st_transform('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')    
merged <- merge(nycc21, nycb20)
View(merged)
```

[image]

You can download reference data here

```
https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/census-download-metadata.page
```

Comment: thanks/sorry! When I try merging(shapefile1, shapefile2) I get a shapefile that matches the polygon in shapefile1, and with the attribute columns of both but with null values for the attributes of shapefil2

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the resulting polygon with null values

Comment: Which out of the 15 datasets on the linked website are you using?...

Comment: I am using the 2020 census block (clipped to shoreline) fine and the 2021 city council district file (release D). 

I was able to successfully complete a spatial join via QGIS, but I need to be able to streamline the process as I will need to repeat for several dozen cities.

Comment: There is no `2021 City Council District` data available under the link you provided. Can you check again?

Comment: Apologies—it takes some digging through the website. Here’s a more direct link: https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/districts-download-metadata.page